# How do I refresh the Google calendar in Gnome?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, calendar

I'm using Gnome 3.14 on Arch Linux. I'm fond of the calendar drop-down when you click on the time in the top panel. I've set up my Google calendar to show there, but if I happen to be offline when logging in, the calendar is not shown.

Is there a way to manually refresh the Gnome calendar?

Comment: How did you set up the Google calendar to show up there?

Comment: I added my Google account to the "Online accounts" app and enabled the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the calendar is embedded in the Gnome shell, rebooting the shell might work. By terminal you can go `gnome-shell --replace`, or you can try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

If that doesn't work it might be possible to [debug the extension](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeOnlineAccounts/Debugging), or otherwise set up a hierarchy that defaults to the usual Gnome calendar when the [Google calendar](https://people.freedesktop.org/~david/gnome-online-accounts-3.1.0/GoaCalendar.html) is inaccessible.

Comment: gnome-shell --replace restart all gnome session (at least on Ubuntu 22). Just issue this command if you don´t have any other app running.